# How to rename files, moving parts of filename and converting date format, with batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, filenames, rename

I use the notability app on the iphone & ipad to save class notes but it saves them with awkward file names such as:

"Title Sep 29, 2014 - 2nd Description blah blah.pdf"
"Title Oct 1, 2014 - 2nd Description blah blah.pdf"

This makes it difficult to sort the files in windows file explorer by date as it sorts it alphabetically and the month is the first thing it sorts due to the file name.

I would like to change the file name structure to:
"YYYY-MM-DD - Title - Description blah blah.pdf"

I assume I would need a for loop to use the ren command but the difficulty I'm having is reading the filename and changing the string structure. The title and 2nd description will vary and be composed of more than one word so it cannot be a hard coded string which makes this even trickier. Anybody have any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: That's too tough for a BAT program, it does not shine for processing strings and dates. It might be better done in any full featured programming language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Too tough for batch"? I see the comedians are loose again...

Now it would have been good to have some real examples, but this should work.

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
FOR %%a IN ("%sourcedir%\*.pdf") DO (
 SET "oname=%%a"
 FOR /f "tokens=1,2*delims=,-" %%c IN ("%%~nxa") DO (
  SET "oldendname=%%e"
  CALL :formdate %%d %%c
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
:: parameters are yyyy unknown* Mon dd
:formdate
SET /a yyyy=%1 2>NUL
IF %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 GOTO :EOF 
SET "newtitle="
:formloop
SHIFT
IF "%~3" neq "" SET "newtitle=%newtitle% %~1"&GOTO formloop
SET "mm="
FOR %%z IN (
 "Jan=01" "Feb=02" "Mar=03" "Apr=04" "May=05" "Jun=06" 
 "Jul=07" "Aug=08" "Sep=09" "Oct=10" "Nov=11" "Dec=12"
 ) DO FOR /f "tokens=1,2delims==" %%m IN (%%z) DO IF "%%m"=="%1" SET "mm=%%n"
IF NOT DEFINED mm GOTO :EOF 
SET /a dd=100+%2

ECHO(REN "%oname%" "%yyyy%-%mm%-%dd:~-2%%newtitle% -%oldendname%"
GOTO :eof
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

[Edit : fixed to include extension]

Comment: Clever - but insane.  Frankly, this is a good example of why you should user VBScript ... or Powershell ... or *ANYTHING* besides .bat files syntax.  IMHO...

Comment: I am just a ordinary PC-user but everytime i see your solutions @Magoo i want to be programmer. Good work.

Comment: LMFAO. It worked. flawlessly. I added .pdf in the 2nd filename of the ren.

Comment: Ah - yes. Found I'd named my test files `....pdf.pdf` fixed so that extension is included in `oldendname` so that the filename-mask needs only to be changed in one place if it's changed.

Comment: @JohnDOE : Not a well-thought-out ambition, unfortunately. Nowadays, every florist, jockey and train-driver is demanding their "right" to be educated in programming at public expense in order to get the big bucks. The government pours money into "education." Meanwhile, people with decades of experience are excluded from jobs because of the abundance of cheap "new grads" with expertise learned from books. After 13 jobless years, having one expert describe the job as "too tough" is a red rag to a bull. It may be insane to tackle the job in this way - is it as insane as public "education" policy?

Comment: I too answered because of the "too tough" comment, but wonder: As a no-code question, if the comment weren't there should this have been answered at all? Would you have answered anyway? Trying to figure out how to handle such questions.

Comment: @sjoy : Yes, I don't really care about "policy" and "rules" that are the mainstay of others' existence. If it looks like an interesting problem, it's fair game. If OP (in general) doesn't know how to start, then my opinion is that this is an opportunity to demonstrate how. It may be useful to later browsers, and it keeps me amused - which keeps me and my shotgun off of the street...

Comment: You are right @Magoo but i belive you are loving this programming. I am just an ordinary PC-user. I love programming too (i am sucky one btw). But when i programming i feel like seeing the face of god (Pardon my expression if you are not a beliver) and thats what metter for me. Yes its useless/pointless in many country but still worth it for me. I hope one day i can quit my worthless job and become a programmer.

Comment: Whoa - John Doe's innocent complement must have touched a raw nerve. That was quite a rant from Magoo.

Answer (score 0):

**New solution using JREN.BAT version 2**

For those that like regular expressions, this is very simple using [JREN.BAT version 2](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081) - a hybrid JScript/batch command line utility that renames files or folders by applying a regular expression search and replace to the name. JREN.BAT is pure script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

This simple one line liner will rename files in the current directory:

```
jren "^(.* )([A-Z][a-z]{2} \d\d?, \d{4}) -" "ts({dt:$2,fmt:'{iso-dt}'})+' - '+$1+'-'" /j /fm *.pdf
```

Add the `/P rootPath` option to rename files in a different directory.

Add the `/S` option to recursively rename files in all the sub-directories

If you are worried about false date matches, you could make the regex more precise:

```
jren "^(.* )((?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) \d\d?, \d{4}) -" "ts({dt:$2,fmt:'{iso-dt}'})+' - '+$1+'-'" /j /fm *.pdf
```

**Here is the original solution using version 1**

Here are two alternative solutions using [JREN.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "src=."
if "%~1" neq "" set "src=%~1" 

::         ($1-)    ($2-) ($3-) ($4-) ($5-) ($6-) ($7-) ($8-) ($9-) ($10) ($11) ($12) ($13)  ($14--)  ($15--)($16------------)
set "find=^(.+?) (?:(Jan)|(Feb)|(Mar)|(Apr)|(May)|(Jun)|(Jul)|(Aug)|(Sep)|(Oct)|(Nov)|(Dec)) (\d\d?), (\d{4})((?: - .+)?\.pdf)$"

set "repl=for (i=1; i<=12; i++) if (eval('$'+(i+1))) rtn=$15+'-'+lpad(i,'00')+'-'+lpad($14,'00')+' - '+$1+$16; rtn;"

call jren "%find%" "%repl%" /j /i /p "%src%"
```

or

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "src=."
if "%~1" neq "" set "src=%~1" 

::         ($1-) ($2--------------------------------------------------------------)($3-------------)
set "find=^(.+?) ((?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) \d\d?, \d{4})((?: - .+)?\.pdf)$"

set "repl=dt=new Date($2); dt.getFullYear()+'-'+lpad(dt.getMonth()+1,'00')+'-'+lpad(dt.getDate(),'00')+' - '+$1+$3;"

call jren "%find%" "%repl%" /j /i /p "%src%"
```

Name either of the above as `renameNotes.bat`, and then use `renameNotes` without arguments to rename files in the current directory, or `renameNotes somePath` to rename files in a particular folder. The script can safely be run multiple times - it will only rename files that require it.

As it stands now, the above solutions require a fair amount of user supplied JScript code. I think I may add a built-in date formatter to JREN.BAT in the near future that would make this even simpler.